# Jquery: Better optimized way of assigning value if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

```
var buyersEmail; 
emailExist = $("#emailTick").is(':checked');
if (emailExist) {
   buyersEmail = boxObj.find("#txtEmail").val();
}
else {
   buyersEmail = "";
}
```

I think there is better way of doing this. Can someone suggest? I want to remove this if else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in such cases.

```
var buyersEmail = $("#emailTick").is(':checked') ? boxObj.find("#txtEmail").val() : '';
```